# Generate DDL using jooq by using schema and table name

Tags: java, sql, jooq

i want to generate DDL using schema and table name for any database..
Below is the code which I'm trying:

```
DSLContext dSLContext = DSL.using(getPostgresqlDataSource().getConnection());
Queries ddl = dSLContext.ddl(DefaultCatalog.DEFAULT_CATALOG.WORLD_SEED.ATM);

for (Query query : ddl.queries()) {
    System.out.println(query);
}

private static DataSource getPostgresqlDataSource() { 
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl(System.getenv("WORLD_JDBC_URL"));
    dataSource.setUsername(System.getenv("WORLD_JDBC_USERNAME"));
    dataSource.setPassword(System.getenv("WORLD_JDBC_PASSWORD"));
    return dataSource;
}
```

Here the schema name and table name has been used from the generated object, but i want to give those two as an input without generating objects

Comment: Trying to understand what you are asking, you effectively want a programatic equivalent of the sqlite dump command (just schema, not values) in a database agnostic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could access live meta information from your JDBC connection via [`DSLContext.meta()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#meta--), filter by the schema and tables that you're interested in, and pass that to the `ddl()` method. Do note that `org.jooq.Meta` references slightly less meta information than generated code, so your DDL might not reflect the exact original model.

Comment: Thanks to reply!.. i have done what I wanted, with below code -  DSLContext dSLContext = DSL.using(getPostgresqlDataSource().getConnection());     Queries ddl = dSLContext.ddl(dSLContext.meta().getTables("banks"));     for (Query query : ddl.queries()) {
   System.out.println(query);
  }

Comment: I'm not able to retrieve the DDL with oracle database which i have tried for postgres database using same code..

Comment: @neha: Would you mind asking a new question? It will probably work much better than the comments. If you think you've found a bug, you may also report it here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new

Comment: Sure Lukas, I have mentioned the issue which I have faced for Oracle Database, https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8480